# Update a column with a varchar + incrementing int

Tags: sql, db2

I'm trying to update the two columns in a table by feeding a list data from the same table. Below is the format I want to update the two columns with

```
LOGIN                         EMAIL 
-----                         -----
5717-9889-0001@xxxx.com       5717-9889-0001@xxxx.com
5717-9889-0002@xxxx.com       5717-9889-0002@xxxx.com
5717-9889-0003@xxxx.com       5717-9889-0003@xxxx.com
```

Below is the query I wrote halfway. I'm actually not sure this is the correct way as I have refereed this from another thread. Obviously it not correct.

```
DECLARE @IncrementValue1 INT
DECLARE @IncrementValue2 INT
SET @IncrementValue1 = 0001
SET @IncrementValue2 = 0001
UPDATE
    USERTEST 
SET
    LOGIN = '5717-9889-' + @IncrementValue1 + '@xxxx.com',
    EMAIL = '5717-9889-' + @IncrementValue2 + '@xxxx.com'
WHERE
    USERID IN ( SELECT
                    USERID 
                FROM
                    USERTEST 
                WHERE
                    LOGIN IN ('advw@12233318007262',
                    'caeqveewe',
                    'zxy@vdv',
                    'zstclair',
                    'zpasigna',
                    'zoe_tadvadv',
                    'zmadvadvadv',
                    'zadvadvadv',
                    'zielinsm@advadvadv.com',
                    'zhouxinhy',
                    'ZHEJIANG@BBAGGS',
                    'ZHE@avadvadv'))
```

Appreciate any help on this

Desired result should look like this. I have around 200+ ids per Document

```
LOGIN                         EMAIL 
-----                         -----
5717-9889-0001@xxxx.com       5717-9889-0001@xxxx.com
5717-9889-0002@xxxx.com       5717-9889-0002@xxxx.com
5717-9889-0003@xxxx.com       5717-9889-0003@xxxx.com
5717-9889-0004@xxxx.com       5717-9889-0004@xxxx.com
5717-9889-0005@xxxx.com       5717-9889-0005@xxxx.com
5717-9889-0006@xxxx.com       5717-9889-0006@xxxx.com
5717-9889-0007@xxxx.com       5717-9889-0007@xxxx.com
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get incrimented ids using `row_number()`, and adding leading zeros to those integers using `LPAD` :

If you need to concatenate two strings use `||` ( `+` is the addition operator )

If you want to start from 11 for example add 10 to `row_number()` : `LPAD(10 + row_number() over(), 4, '0' )`

```
UPDATE USERTEST
SET
    LOGIN = '5717-9889-' || LPAD(row_number() over(), 4, '0' ) || '@xxxx.com',
    EMAIL = '5717-9889-' || LPAD(row_number() over(), 4, '0' ) || '@xxxx.com'
WHERE LOGIN IN ('advw@12233318007262',
                    'caeqveewe',
                    'zxy@vdv',
                    'zstclair',
                    'zpasigna',
                    'zoe_tadvadv',
                    'zmadvadvadv',
                    'zadvadvadv',
                    'zielinsm@advadvadv.com',
                    'zhouxinhy',
                    'ZHEJIANG@BBAGGS',
                    'ZHE@avadvadv');
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/cuV7fBSV)